# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Point' and 'str'

Tags: python, geopy

I was trying to write a file with all the coordinates at a 10 mile distance from a center point but when I run the program it gives me this error:

> File "______", line 11, in <"module>
>
> distance_data.write(element + "\n")
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Point' and 'str'

I would really appreciate help. Thanks a lot!!

My code:

```
import geopy.distance
distance_data = open("Distance from ____.txt", "w")
distance_data_to_add = []
for i in range (3600):
    bearing = i*.1
    lat = 51.8983
    long = 177.1822667
    new_lat_long = geopy.distance.distance(miles=10).destination((lat, long), bearing=bearing)
    distance_data_to_add.append(new_lat_long)
    for element in distance_data_to_add:
        distance_data.write(element + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with objects of different types then you can't use the "+" operator just like the error is showing.

Try previously converting `element` to string with:

```
distance_data.write(str(element) + "\n")
```

Comment: Or use an f-string: `distance_data.write(f"{element}\n")`.

Comment: Thanks so much!! It works perfectly now!